# Saving selected option (combo box) on database in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am editing a site, I made a combo box that has this code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="trig" name="user_list">
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <option value="{{$item->id}}"
            @if ( $item->id ==  $listid[0]->user_list )
            selected
            @endif
        >
        {{ $item->first_name }} {{ $item->middle_initial }} {{ $item->last_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
{{ $listid }}
```

and here is my controller in the edit part:

```
$items = List::all(['id', 'first_name','middle_initial','last_name']);
```

and tried this code for the store (save) :

```
$items->users->create([
    'data' => $request->user_list(
        'user_list'
    ),
]);
```

how to save it to the database?
any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
here is the error at log.

> [2019-08-22 00:19:59] local.ERROR: Exception: Property [user_list]
>   does not exist on this collection instance. in /home/site/main_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1650
>
> Next ErrorException: Property [user_list] does not exist on this
>   collection instance. (View:
>   /home/site/main_site/resources/views/backend/access/edit.blade.php)
>   in /home/site/main_site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1650

Comment: ...and what is your question exactly?

Comment: it is not saving in the database, how to make it store the data to the database?

Comment: Are there any errors reported on the browser? Also, you can check the log at `storage/logs/laravel.log`  for any errors. If there are, then include them in the question.

Comment: You incorrectly accessed the input value using `$request->user_list('user_list')`. Try `$request->input('user_list')`.

Comment: hello, updated it, but still its not saving in the database